# Search file names in AppCode

Tags: appcode

Is there a way to search all the file names in my project?

In Xcode the lens on the bottom searches through the names of all the files in the project and it's a very quick and intuitive way to navigate a project you are familiar with.
Is there something similar in Appcode?

Comment: I would also recommend [AppCode Tips'n'Tricks](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/category/tipsntricks/) blog section with a articles about navigation, completion and efficient use of the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following text was found on the AppCode basic web site.. This practice will definitely helps you to find the files using AppCode IDE within your project.

> When working on your own project, you often know which file or class you want to open and edit. The fastest way to do this is to use Go to Class... (Cmd+O) or Go to File... (Cmd+Shift+O).

e.g [image]

You can also find excluded project files as well.

Please check [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/quickstart/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Is there any way to filter out some directories from Cmd+Shift+O search popup? (I know it is already possible in Cmd+Shift+F “Search In Path” dialog).